# How can I load test a Web RTC group call

Tags: webrtc, load-testing, kurento

I am using

- Kurento Media Server
- Node.JS Signal Server
- JS based group call client

How I may automate load testing of group call. JMeter like solution wont work because they are unable to understand WebSocket / SPAs

Manually testing can only work with 8 to 20 users, but I need a way to test maximum load on Video Infrastructure.

Comment: Websockets and WebRTC are 2 different things, so what do you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

> JMeter like solution wont work because they are unable to understand WebSocket

JMeter supports WebSocket load testing via [WebSocket Sampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler) see [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) guide for installation and usage instructions

In regards to other free and open source tools if you don't like JMeter for any reason, here are some:

- [Websocket - Gatling Documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/http/websocket.html#websocket)
- [Tsung - Sessions -> WebSocket](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-sessions.html#websocket)

In regards to SPA (if I'm correctly interpreting it as Single Page Application) - given correct JMeter (or other load testing tool) configuration to deal with embedded resources and proper AJAX requests simulation it shouldn't be a problem to conduct your test.